# continuous fonctions with compact support and Radon measure(foliations by Borel sets for positive Radon measures)

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

Hi everyone

Let $f\in C_c(\mathbb{R}^d)$ $f\geq 0$, Im trying to show that  the set $$T=\left\{t \neq 0: \mu\left(f^{-1}\{t\}\right)>0\right\}$$

is at most countable where $\mu$ is a positive radon measure. here is what i did

Let C be a set of nonzero real numbers , since the sets $\{f^{-1}\{t_i\}\}_{t_i\in C}$ are pairwise disjoint borel sets all included in $supp(f)$ we have
$$\mu(supp(f))\geq\mu(\bigcup_{t_i\in C}f^{-1}\{t_i\})=\sum_{t_i\in C}\mu(f^{-1}\{t_i\})$$

my quesion is : if we suppose that T isnt at most countable, how to choose the set C to find a contradiction. in the attached photo they didnt tell how.

PS :in the literature they call it the foliations by Borel sets for positive Radon measures Lemma

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to check that $T=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} T_n$, where $T_n:=\left\{t \neq 0: \mu\left(f^{-1}\{t\}\right)>\frac{1}{n}\right\}$, $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Also $\infty > \mu(supp(f))$ since $\mu$ is radon and $f\in C_c(\mathbb{R}^d)$.

Lets assume that $T$ is uncountable. Then there are infinitely many $t\neq 0$, such that $\mu(f^{-1}\{t\})>\frac{1}{n_0}$ for some $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$  (uncountably many to be more precise, otherwise $T$ would be countable). That leads to the contradiction:
$$\infty > \mu(supp(f))\geq\mu(\bigcup_{t\in T_{n_0}}f^{-1}\{t\})=\sum_{t\in T_{n_0}}\mu(f^{-1}\{t\}) > \sum_{m\in \mathbb{N}\\t_m\in T_{n_0}\\ t_m\neq t_{m'}, \ m\neq m'}\mu(f^{-1}\{t_m\}) > \sum_{m\in \mathbb{N}}\frac{1}{n_0}=\infty$$

Comment: thank you sir for your response
if i understand right : if we suppose that T isnt at most countable then there exists a $n_0$ such that $T_{n_0}$ is infinite and uncountable, then we chose a countable set C in $T_{n_0}$ and sum over it to get a serie greater that the harmonic serie which converges to $\infty$ whence the contradiction.

Comment: that's almost the claim. this is not the harmonic series. it's $\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}}a_n$ where $a_n=1$; or if you like $a_n=\frac{1}{n_0}$, where $n_0$ is a fixed natural number.

Comment: sorry you're right it's not the harmonic series , thank you very much sir for your response

Comment: you are welcome